# XAML Content Page Not Properly Being Added To Project

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

i'm learning Xamarin and I'm having a small issue. I can't seem to be able to create a ContentView or ContentPage as when I do, the code behind adds fine, but the XAML page is not visible in the solution explorer. The XAML file is being generated as it's visible within Windows File Explorer, but it does not show up like it should in the Solution Explorer. I have revealed it using the "Show All Files" option in the Solution Explorer, but it appears to have a whited out icon next to it. [My Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tS2X.png)

Comment: Have you modified the .csproj of your TestCrossPlatform project?

Comment: No, should I be?

Comment: No, but it could have been a reason for not showing up on VS. I'm just curious, what happens if you double click on it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j8nLL50L I don't think it's the same project as the screenshot before, but the problem still persists in it. My ContentPage is named TestPage

Comment: Right click on your XAML file and include it in your project.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: There is something wrong with your .csproj, it's not the normal structure of the file. It's missing the ItemGroup that includes the file to be compiled and the PropertyGroups. Try to do a fresh new project and/or compare it with what you have

Comment: I've created multiple projects on two computers. I have no idea what's wrong. At first I thought it could be that i'm selecting the wrong type of Item but I'm pretty much lost now. For reference, I'm creating a Cross Platform App, and I'm creating a Content View for Xamarin.Forms. Could it be an issue with visual studio?

Comment: I've found the issue. I didn't have Universal Windows Platform installed. This seemed to fix everything.